# Custom Training in Tensorflow 1.12

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a model using Custom Training methods. I have successfully run/executed the following:

1. Making Model
2. Getting Data in `for` loop.
3. Initialize `Adam` optimizer.
4. Get a loss value.

And then the problem starts. In the recent version of TF, we have `apply_gradient` method for optimizers to apply gradients generated from loss value. But in TF1.12 it is not the case, there is no such function.

And now I am unable to figure out how should I apply my gradients from loss function to optimizers.

Comment: can you show the code where you initialize the optimizer?

Comment: I will update the question now. Actually, I found out that TF1.12 never had Adam.apply_gradient method. (See https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/r1.12/site/en/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam.md)